# Display two column of Products on mobile view in woocommerce

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using sshop theme for my woocommerce store https://techcart.pk. I want to add two columns instead of one for all screen resolutions below 768px. theme shows two column at 768px but on mobile screen theme shows only one column of product. Any CSS code of function to solve this?? [image: mobile view of theme]

[image]

Comment: You have to modify your theme's style.css, open rendered page source and see which selectors needs modification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By editing in existing style.css you can do it check this screenshot

```
@media screen and (max-width: 570px)
.eq-row-col-4 .eq-col {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    clear: none !important;
}
```

[image]